# Are children's ears more vulnerable to loud noise than adults?

Tags: hearing, human-ear

I am interested , what are child's ear development stages?
Do newborns' have already developed (defensed) ear like adults have and there is no much difference with regard being vulnerable toward sudden burst noise, which we (adults) bear easier (i.e. popper burst within 1 meter range)?

Comment: I would suggest that this type of question, not relating to specific biological processes, might be more appropriate on SE Medical Sciences.

Comment: @David sorry, but there is no chance such question to be accepted on medicals.se. I have experience there. my question is formed to be non-medical and it is about ear-development stages.